# Inverting a matrix (Mod 26)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to invert the matrix

A= \begin{bmatrix}17&20\\15&40\end{bmatrix}

I calculate the $\det(k)=16$

But I can't invert 16 (mod 26)
So I am unsure where to go from here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible. It is easy to see that if $A$ is invertible then $\det (A) \det (A^{-1}) = \det(AA^{-1}) = 1$. So your matrix isn't invertible. Also $$ \begin{pmatrix} 17 & 20 \\ 15 & 40 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 13 \end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \pmod{26}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A:=\begin{bmatrix}17&20\\15&40\end{bmatrix}$$
then $\det(A)=17\cdot 40-15\cdot 20=380\equiv 16\pmod{26}$ as you say. Since $16^{-1}$ does not exists in $\Bbb Z_{26}$ (because $\gcd(16,26)=2\neq 1$), we see that $\det(A)$ is not invertible. Hence, $A$ is not invertible with coefficients in $\Bbb Z_{26}$, because $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A)$ is invertible.